# How to set up a layout for EditText and Button aligned by the topline?

Tags: android, layout, button, android-edittext

I'm trying to create a kind of "Buttoned Edit" control, when EditText and Button controls are placed in the same line. I used a simple LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextFileName"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Database file name"
        android:inputType="textUri" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFileSelect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="46dip"
        android:text="..." />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is edit box and button are not aligned on the same "topline":
[image: layout topline spacing]

A closer look:
[image]

On a different emulators I'm getting a different spacing.

How to make both EditText and Button to be aligned on a topline always?

**SOLUTION (thanks to @steevoo and @Mohamed_AbdAllah):**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFileSelect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="46dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="..." />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextFileName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buttonFileSelect"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/buttonFileSelect"
        android:hint="Database file name"
        android:inputType="textUri" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try with relative layout there is align top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `RelativeLayout` instead and use `android:layout_alignTop` to align the tops of the `Button` and the `EditText`. Also, you can give them the same fixed height (46dip) but this can cause text to be clipped in the `EditText`